# HTML Form submit data

Tags: html

I have a form on a remote server I'm trying to submit data to, example below

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<form  action="http://www.example.com/post.php"  method="post">
<input type="text" name="input1" value="test1"  />
<input type="text" name="input2" value="test2"  />
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to auto submit the data like this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<form  action="http://www.example.com/post.php"  method="post">
<input type="text" name="input1" value="test1"  />
<input type="text" name="input2" value="test2"  />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 document.forms[0].submit(); 
</script> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine if the first example didn't have a (name="send") name but when it does have a name nothing submits. My question is how would I go about sending the data with a input button that has a name.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The answer turned out to be `type="hidden"` instead of `type="submit"`, in which the second does not allow DOM submission while also submitting that `input`'s value in the GET/POST data. `type="hidden"` does, and it works here since the button does not need to be physically clicked.

---

Pick one:

```
<form name="formname" id="formid" action="http://www.example.com/post.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="input1" value="test1"  />
<input type="text" name="input2" value="test2"  />
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (confirm('Ok for "formname", Cancel for "getElementById"')) {
    console.log('document.formname.submit()');
    document.formname.submit();
} else {
    console.log('document.getElementById("formid").submit()');
    document.getElementById('formid').submit();
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/EAmwj/3

Comment: I tried it and I think there is some confusion not the form name its the button submit has a name and it's looking for name="send" without it the name it don't submit.

Comment: It still works with a `button`: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/EAmwj/3/ Note, you need Firebug in Firefox (or something with a `console`, Chrome (native `console`, or IE9 (native console).

Comment: Yes your example will submit the form so will my second example. The problem is the remote server is looking for the name="send" and if it don't see it, it wont submit anything.

Comment: The problem is the remote server is looking for the name="send" on the submit button.

Comment: Change it from a `submit` to a `hidden` type.

Comment: No problem. Note, if you are using DOM methods to access the `type` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/EAmwj/4/ IE8 and below, I believe, will not let you change the `type` of a form element. In case that's applicable. If you're authoring the file, that should be a problem (just set it to hidden). A `type="submit"` does not have it's value sent unless it has a `name` and it's physically clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript code will get executed as soon as the page is loaded. That is why it gets submitted immediately.

You need to wrap the JS code in a function and let an event call it from the page.

You can use a regular button and set the function for the onclick event of a button.

```
<html>
<head>

<body>
<form  action="http://www.example.com/post.php"  method="post">
<input type="text" name="input1" value="test1"  />
<input type="text" name="input2" value="test2"  />
<input type="button" name="send" value="test2" onclick="doSubmit()"  />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function doSubmit() {
 document.forms[0].submit(); 
}
</script> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```